# MYSQL insert to laravel 5.5 request controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following code that loops through a dynamically created drop down menu and adds each product to an order db.  I've moved the pages into laravel but am stuck at making this part work. Below is my `Legacy Code`:

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, order_id, 
enrolment_id, product_description, delivery_mode, course_cost) VALUES (?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param("iisssi", $payment_cid, $mysql_id, $enrolment_id, 
$mysql_desc, $mysql_mode, $mysql_cost);
$fetchid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);


$result = array_map(function($d, $c, $m) { 
return array('product_description'=>$d, 'course_cost'=>$c, 
'delivery_mode'=>$m); 
}, $product_description, $course_cost, $delivery_mode
);  

// set parameters and execute

foreach($result as $item){
$mysql_id = $fetchid;
$mysql_desc = $item['product_description'];
$mysql_mode = $item['delivery_mode'];
$mysql_cost = $item['course_cost'];
$stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I convert it to `Laravel`. Here is my attempt to save with a CRUD Controller. Top part saves single data input fine however when there are multiple products I run into errors.

```
Hey Serge, yes all code is massive to paste in here so snippets super brief.  My product_description saving snippet is example as this is where I get stuck.
```

Following code I know is wrong as it is a mash of a single save and my attempted loop:

```
$orders = new Order([
'customer_id' => $customers{'id'},
'course_cost' => $request->get('product_cost'),
'order_id' => $customers{'id'},
'enrolment_id' => $customers{'enrolment_id'},
'product_description' => $request->get('product_description'),
'delivery_mode' => $request->get('delivery_mode'),
'course_cost' => $request->get('course_cost'),
]);

$dataSet = [];
foreach ($orders as $item) {
$dataSet[] = [
'product_description'  => $request->get('product_description'),   
];
}
DB::table('orders')->insert($dataSet);
return redirect('/customers');
}
```

Error from current code
[image]

Comment: you will require reading the documentation for Laravel Models to do this

Comment: If you're using Laravel, *use Laravel*. Smashing around with `mysqli` is not making this any easier. This is really standard model code if just inserting values.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing captain obvious. moving this into laravel

Comment: @ParkProductions, hi, i know tadman is kind of Obvious.. but thats the first step, don't blame him. could you specify **Top part saves single data input fine however when there are multiple products I run into errors.** part more? what kind of error you hit? how did you save multiple products? we need the obvious to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I imaging those are code snipets... the single one looks fine... funny product description saving in product description does noting ... lol Imagine it's just an example... but proper eloquent would look like this...

```
$orders = Request::where('product_description', $request->get('product_description')->get();
foreach($orders as $order) {
    order->product_description => $request->get('product_description');
    order->save();
}
```

Comment: Edited original code to show errors and attempt at array insert for product_description